# Arduino Wifi Shield with monitor mode ( promiscuous mode )

Tags: wifi

Is there a WiFi Shield or driver that supports monitor mode and receiving raw packets ?

Comment: What is it that you're specifically that you want to achieve and what research have you done on this already?

Comment: I want to capture probe requests packets essentially.

Comment: I'd like to do something similar and have yet to arrive at an Arduino-based solution. Here's some resources I've found useful in learning about this topic. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54062/how-to-detect-the-hello-packets-sent-by-a-wifi-enabled-smartphone

http://www.engr.uic.edu/pub/Bits/Musa/musa-eriksson-sensys12.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be a shield?

I would consider buying a cheap Wi-Fi router instead with good open-source support and a way to interface it to the Arduino. Their price is near to the price of Wi-Fi shields.

- They consume little power, can be powered by 5V and have built in Wi-Fi.
- Some have a built-in USB port, most have a serial port, which can be used to talk to the Arduino.
- You would have to put custom firmware on it, plus the program which receives the raw packets for you.

Specifically, I would get a TP-Link TL-WR703ND for this task.

- It can be fed 5 Volts, or 3.3 Volts with a little hacking
- It has USB
- It also has serial, and you can even hack an I2C port onto it
- It can run OpenWRT

[More info](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr703n) on this particular router

Comment: You actually gave me a nice idea. Could I plug a 3G modem in the usb port and send the packets over the air?

Comment: Most certainly. On the OpenWRT website you can find instructions on getting the USB modem to work. You can use a hub to plug both the Arduino and the USB modem into the router. But beware that most USB modems communicate using serial-over-USB, so it's easy to mix up the two devices (because Arduinos also do and you will only see two serial ports, numbered by the order they were detected by the system). Also you may have to install the kernel module(s) for the USB/serial chip of the Arduino.

Comment: If this question is still open, I can also suggest using an ESP8266 board. It's a small board with a WiFi-enabled CPU, flash memory and an antenna - so it can be programmed and it can run without the Arduino. It supports promiscuous mode, so I think probe packets can also be captured. Also, it costs less than $4. (It came out in late 2014, about the time you asked the question)